# C# WPF MVVM window dragmove

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть кастомное окно, как сделать в MVVM dragmove для него? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Как и где правильно забиндить mouse event?

Comment: При чем тут MVVM?

Comment: @АндрейNOP а где мне получить window? передавать его в конструкторе view model? и с обработкой event'ов не понимаю..

Comment: @АндрейNOP я не знаю что при чем) потому и спрашиваю)

Comment: Зачем вам Window в ViewModel? Ваша задача чисто вьюшная и решаться должна исключительно на стороне View. Не нужно передавать Window в VM.

Comment: @АндрейNOP тоесть grid может двигать весь window?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Я вас не понимаю. Реализуйте перетаскивание вообще не думая про MVVM, тупо в кодбихайнд и это будет правильно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP те создать event напрямую?

Comment: Да, подписывайтесь на события и реагируйте в MainWindow.xaml.cs